# Keypress to change class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dom-events

I have a problem I can't seem to sort out.

I have a form with a custom styled button (input type=button). When typing in the text field, I want people to be able to press the TAB key and go to the button. However, it won't use a tab-index so my solution was to highlight the label and change the CSS to give the button a new border color. However, the border color will not change on keypress in any browser other than Firefox.

Here is what I have:

```
$(function() {
    $("#email").bind("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                send();
                return false; 

            };

            if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                    $("#submit_btn").removeClass('submit1').addClass('submit1after');
            };

      });
};
```

The first enter keypress is to serialize and email the form and all.

I can't seem to get it to work for the life of me. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better solution to what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thanks for taking the time,

Armik

Comment: Your js looks broken - your missing an end bracket on the closure ie `});` instead of `};`. Remove the trailing semi-colon from your *if* blocks ie `if (...) { }` rather than `if (...) { };`. Finally the jQuery doc's recommend using `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode` http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: The code works fine as is, but I will definitely take your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: It might work today but the syntax is wrong (sorry not broken) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717949/javascript-when-should-i-use-a-semicolon-after-curly-braces

Comment: @ChrisMoutray I had learned that it's good practice to add the semi-colon. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keydown` instead, for me that works (see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/npGtX/2/)

```
$(function () {
  $("#email").bind("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      send();
      return false;    
    };

    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
      $("#submit_btn").removeClass('submit1').addClass('submit1after');
    };
  });
};
```

Also I found this: [Suppressing keyPress for non-character keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907114/suppressing-keypress-for-non-character-keys)

> keypress is not necessarily triggered when the keypress is not a
>   character. So the browser may not trigger an event on backspace, F1,
>   the down key, etc.

Comment: Speransky Danil, this did it for me. Thank you! Should keydown be the default for any keyboard trigger I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `keyup` event and `event` object's `which` property, jQuery normalizes the `which` property and it's cross-browser:

```
$(function() {
    $("#email").bind("keyup", function(e) {
         if (e.which == 13) {
            send();
            return false; 
         };   
         if (e.which == 9) {
            $("#submit_btn").toggleClass('submit1 submit1after');
         };
    });
};
```

Comment: I'll be changing the keyCode to which. However, keydown solved the problem for me, but I'm sure keyup would do the trick as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
$("#email").keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which== 13) {
            send();
            return false; 

        };

        if (e.keyCode == 9 || e.which== 9) {
                $("#submit_btn").removeClass('submit1').addClass('submit1after');
        };

  });
 };
```